# How to configure Symfony JsonResponse output?

Tags: json, symfony

Is there any way to configure `JsonResponse` output to be - for example - unescaped unicode?

something like the output of this php function:

```
json_encode($array, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, here you go:

```
$response = new JsonResponse($data);
$response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

return $response;
```

Comment: And globally, not per invocation?

Comment: Take a look at this example:
https://gist.github.com/diegonobre/341eb7b793fc841c0bba3f2b865b8d66

Answer (score 1):

To do this globally, make an event listener. Something like this:

services.yml:

```
    event_listeners.json_formatter_listener:
        class: EventListeners\JsonResponseFormatterListener
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

JsonResponseFormatterListener.php:

```
<?php

namespace EventListeners;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\FilterResponseEvent;

class JsonResponseFormatterListener
{
    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        if ($response instanceof JsonResponse) {
            $response->setEncodingOptions(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        }
    }
}
```